# Mongo DB community 7.0 on MacOs monterey 12.6

Tags: mongodb

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/marcus/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` exited with 5.

I tried to start my mongodb service but this happened. I tried reinstalling homebrew and mongodb-community and it is still like this.